# solve for $A$ in $\cos A+\cos2A+\cos3A=0$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $A$ where, $0°\leq A\leq 360°$

$\cos A+\cos2A+\cos3A=0$

My attempt;

Here, 
$$\cos A+\cos2A+\cos3A=0$$
$$\cos A+2\cos^2A-1+4\cos^3A-3\cos A=0$$
$$4\cos^3A+2\cos^2A-2\cos A-1=0$$.

Now, what should I do to move on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need multiple angle formulas.

$\cos A+\cos 3A = 2 \cos A \cos 2A$

$\cos A+\cos 2A+\cos 3A=0=(\cos 2A)(1+2\cos A)$

Then $\cos 2A=0$ or $\cos A=-1/2$, both of which are easily solved.

Answer (score 3):

$$4cos^{ 3 }A+2cos^{ 2 }A-2cosA-1=0\\ 2\cos ^{ 2 }{ A } \left( 2\cos { A } +1 \right) -\left( 2\cos { A } +1 \right) =0\\ \left( 2\cos { A } +1 \right) \left( 2\cos ^{ 2 }{ A } -1 \right) =0\\ \cos { A } =-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } ,\cos ^{ 2 }{ A } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \Rightarrow \cos { A } =\pm \frac { \sqrt { 2 }  }{ 2 } \\ $$ can you proceed?

Comment: Could you please show me the answers. I am having problem there too.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
\cos\alpha+\cos\beta=2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}
$$
Apply with $\alpha=3A$ and $\beta=A$.